# Third Order PDE written as a System of (Linear) First Order PDEs

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I need to rewrite the PDE $$f_{y}+ff_{x}+f_{xxx}=0,$$ where $f=f(x,y)$ as a system of first order quasi-linear PDEs.

I have no idea how to tackle this problem. Any form of help will be appreciated. Are there any methodologies for such questions?

Thanks,
Jay.

Comment: You could rewrite it as a 3rd order nonlinear ode.  The most general solution is $f=x^{-2}g(\mu)$ where $\mu=\frac{x^3}{y}$.  If you take derivatives and substitute you get $$27\mu^3g^{(3)}+(24\mu+3\mu g-\mu^2)g'-2g^2-24g=0$$  Use numerical techniques to find $g$ and you're done.  I know you weren't asked to solve the equation, but this approach (dreamed up by American mathematician Garrett Birkhoff) is a dandy approach when you've got to have an answer.

Comment: Dear @atomteori, Thanks for the additional approach. Very interesting. Can you direct me to an appropriate link to learn more about this? In particular, how were the forms of $f$ and $\mu$ selected.

Comment: This is an application of Lie theory.  The first task is to find a Lie group invariant to your DEQ, in this case $G(x,y,f)=(\lambda x,

Comment: Sorry, didn't get to finish last comment.  Here's the rest.  $G(x,y,f)=(\lambda x,\lambda^3 y,\lambda^{-2} f)\lambda_o=1$  Now find a couple of non-trivial stabilizers for the group, such as $\mu=\frac{x^3}{y}$ and $\nu=fx^2$, set $\nu=g(\mu)$ and you're off to the races.  A good reference is Lawrence Dresner's Similarity Solutions of Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations, ISBN 0-273-08621-9   It's probably out of print but you can find it on Amazon or Ebay, I think.  Haven't checked recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $g=f_x$ so $f_{xx}=g_x$. Now $h=g_x$ so $f_{xxx}=?$. Just add more dependent variables  (unknown functions)

Comment: Dear @Sergio Parreiras, Thanks. So, $ f_{xxx}=g_{xx}=h_{x} $. Question: How do I write the aforementioned substitutions together with the (now reduced) original PDE as a system?

Comment: You will have additional equations, just make sure every term in each equation has first or zero order. The first equation $g-f_x=0$ and also the third I wrote should be in the new system but not the second.

Comment: Dear @Sergio Parreiras, Thanks. So, I believe one more equation is required to complete the system. Last one is $f_{y}+fg+h_{x}=0 $?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Unrelated: do you know what is an integrability condition for a PDE?

Comment: Thanks. I don't think so. However, I know that the above equation has a reduction to a Painleve equation, which is an integrable ODE.